# Persisting data and pulling from firebase on launch

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

I'm working on an app that stores users' current locations anytime a "Tag Location" button is pressed. Those locations are then annotated on *every* user's map. Firebase is my backend. Everything works fine on one screen during one launch, but I don't know how to proceed with multiple users and multiple launches.

My question is, **how do I have all previous annotations in the database (and annotations made by User B while User A is not using the app) load onto the map upon launch?**

Firebase listeners for new Latitudes and Longitudes in `viewDidLoad()`

```
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Latitude").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.latitude = snapshot.value as? CLLocationDegrees
    })
    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Longitude").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.longitude = snapshot.value as? CLLocationDegrees
    })
```

Updating user's current location:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    if let loc = userLocation.location {
        centerMapOnLocation(location: loc)

    }
    myLatitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    myLongitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
}
```

Storing coordinates upon button press, then pulling them back from Firebase base into an annotation:

```
@IBAction func tagLocationBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    var annotationArray = [MKAnnotation]()
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    if myLatitude != nil && myLongitude != nil {
        ref?.child("Latitude").childByAutoId().setValue(myLatitude)
        ref?.child("Longitude").childByAutoId().setValue(myLongitude)
    }


    if latitude != nil && longitude != nil {
        coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate!
        annotationArray.append(annotation)
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotationArray)
    }
```

I've read Firebase documentation on persistence and Apple's guidelines on NSCoding, but I am still unsure of how to proceed and what to implement. I'm not necessarily looking for code, but more so for direction. Thank you!